# I want int data from cursor help me please

Tags: android

```
public Cursor ShowBarchartIncome(int yearChoose) {
    Cursor cur1=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COLEXPENSE+" as _id,"+" SUM(PRICE) as price from "+EXPENSETABLE
    +" WHERE ("+YEAREX+" = "+2012+") AND ("+MONTHEX+" = 01) AND ("+TYPE+" = 'income')",new String [] {});
    return cur1;    
  }
public class BarGraph { 
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        DBHelper.open();            
        int spn=editYEAR.getId();
        int e = Integer.valueOf(spn);
        c = DBHelper.ShowBarchartIncome(e);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        //data 1
        int[] y ={**c.getCount()**,443,443,456,234,123,342,134,123,645,234,274};
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("รายรับ");
        for(int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
        series.add("Bar "+ (i+1),y[i]);     
    }
}
```

I can't get true data sum price it return 1 to  `int[] y ={c.getCount()}`

How can I get data sum price in showbarchartincome if true data is 15000

Answer (score 2):

Try insead of `new String [] {}` just use null.

```
Cursor cur1=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COLEXPENSE+" as _id,"+" SUM(PRICE) as price from "+EXPENSETABLE
            +" WHERE ("+YEAREX+" = "+2012+") AND ("+MONTHEX+" = 01) AND ("+TYPE+" = 'income')", null);
```

**Update:**

To get data from the cursor you should add the following lines:

```
c.moveToFirst();
price = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("price"));

c.getCount() just show the number of returned records.
```